# Hide and than Show a Div - Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, show-hide

I'm creating a HTML5 game and I want to have a new div (containing my main menu) to pop up when I click the enter button on my splash page. I've been successful with having the main menu div pop up when clicking the button and hiding the splash page, but have not been able to hide the main menu page before clicking the button, it appears when the page is loading but than disappears like it is supposed to. I hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance for any assistance

```
$("#mainmenu").hide();

$("#enter").click(function () { 
$("#main").hide();
$("#mainmenu").show();
return false;
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#mainmenu" ).hide( "slow", function() {
    //insert show query here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out it was because my loader animation placeholder code was running before my jquery was firing thank you !